# Can I cast a spell multiple times in one round across different investigators if I trade it?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Can I cast a spell and then have it traded to another investigator to cast that round?
This would work great with Blessing of Isis to ensure blessings all around.

Some spells say "once a round you may etc" so my thinking is that **these** cannot be cast more than once, but the wording literally could still mean each investigator can cast it once per round right?
After all, it would seem like they are meant to keep an investigator from preventing healing or stamina loss from all attacks all the time, which is sensible.
Passing it to another to cast once themselves sounds like a reasonable ruling.
Is there an official ruling?

Comment: Seems reasonable.  I know of nothing official and despite the love of "whatever favors you the least is what it is" notation, in this case I'd agree if it doesn't say you can't perform those series of actions, you can.  If you prefer this to be an answer, I can do that.

Comment: Although these matters may seem related, they are in fact governed by separate rules and should be asked in two separate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for Spells that require an action:
No, you can't use these again after trading.

> Like all actions, each component action can only be performed
>   once per round. Multiple investigators **cannot** perform the same
>   action on a component during a single round, except for local
>   actions. For example, if an investigator uses a component action
>   on an Asset and then trades it to another investigator, the new
>   owner cannot use the component action that round.

Source: [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), "Component Action" (page 3)

As for Spells that can be triggered "Once per round":
No, they can't be used again after trading.
The "once per round" limitation is tied to the possession not to an investigator possessing it.
When then possession is traded, the limitation moves with it and doesn't reset.

Comment: Great find, I knew I had read that somewhere but couldn't find it!

Comment: What about two investigators having the same card each using their own copy? It seems that this is allowed. If yes, what about a single character using two different copies in the same turn? Is the character then allowed to perform the same action twice in one turn. (This last scenario of course requires some mechanism to get an extra action such as Charlie's ability so that the two copies can be switched since he can't hold both at the same time.)

Comment: @Kvothe If a single character manages to somehow switch their used-this-round copy for a not-used-this-round-yet copy of the same card, they will be able to perform an identical action for a second time. A similar situation is when different components feature an identical action (example: Enchanted Bow and Monster Hunter). In both cases you would perform two identical actions which is different from performing the same action twice.

Answer (score 3):

A *component* can only be used once per turn.

> Although an investigator cannot perform a component action from a
>   single component more than once each round, he can perform component
>   actions of different components

It's not a specific 'investigator' but 'any' investigator that cannot use the component more than once.

So the "use" of a card kind of "sticks" to the card and cannot be used by another investigator.